# Difference between Option handling using "for" and "match" in Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming, pattern-matching, monads, option-type

I'm currently learning Scala and came across two different ways to handle Options. The results are the same, but I'm wondering if there is a advantage of using one over the other (or if there is something even better).

The functions divByTwo1 and divByTwo2 will return the input divided by 2, if the input could also be evenly divided by 4, otherwise it will return None.

```
def divByFour(i: Int): Option[Int] = {
    if (i % 4 == 0) {
        Some(i / 4)
    } else {
        None
    }
}

def divByTwo1(i: Int): Option[Int] = {
    for {
        fourth <- divByFour(i)
    } yield fourth * 2
}

def divByTwo2(i: Int): Option[Int] = {
    divByFour(i) match {
        case Some(fourth) => Some(fourth * 2)
        case None         => None
    }
}
```

Comment: The first one is equivalent to `divByFour(i).map(fourth => fourth * 4)`. And the second way is equivalent at the implementation of `map`. So, basically all three alternatives are doing the _"same"_. - Now, which one is better is more a opinion-based question than a real technical difference. There is an _"advantage"_ in using `map` or **for** instead of pattern matching, and it is that the code is more generic. i.e. That you can use any **Monad** with the same code, and the semantics are the same, apply a function to an effectual value.

Comment: It is really a opinion based, you can user either. Depends on your style, and what you think that gives more readability.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The cleanest version is probably this:

```
def divByTwo(i: Int): Option[Int] = divByFour(i).map(_ * 2)
```

As a general rule, I would use `map`/`flatMap`/`filter` when the result is an `Option` because it keeps the computation inside the `Option` container. Use `match`/`fold`/`getOrElse` when you are extracting the data from the `Option` container and the result is some other type.

Use `for` as a convenient way of handling multiple `map`/`flatMap`/`filter` calls but I personally avoid it for a single `map` call.